# "Al n'tilat yadayim" on fast days

Tags: blessing, yom-kippur, netilat-yadayim-washing, shacharis-morning-prayer, tisha-bav

On Tisha b'Av and Yom Kippur, we are not supposed to lave our hands. Resultantly, on Tisha b'Av and Yom Kippur, do we say "baruch… n'tilat yadayim" in birchot hashachar?

Comment: _Kitzur Shulchan Aruch_ 124:7 [in English](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur124.html#7) indeed says that washing is forbidden on the Ninth of Av. Yet it then lists a number of exceptions, beginning with the following: "However, [washing] that is not for pleasure is permitted, and so one can wash one's hands in the morning. One should be careful to only wash the fingers". I presume that your Halachic source was an extremely concise summary, and so it didn't have room to list any exceptions. Am I correct?

Comment: Why would you think we would? On Shabbat Rosh Hashana we don't blow the Shofar. Do we still say "baruch... lishmoa kol shofar"?

Answer (score 5):

This statement is inaccurate:
`On Tisha b'Av and Yom Kippur, we are not supposed to lave our hands.`

As we learn in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in סימן קכד - הלכות תשעה באב laving hands and getting wet in general is not a problem, if not done for pleasure:

> וְאֵינָהּ אֲסוּרָה רַק רְחִיצָה שֶׁל תַּעֲנוּג. אֲבָל שֶׁלֹּא לְתַעֲנוּג, מֻתָּר. וְלָכֵן רוֹחֵץ יָדָיו בְּשַׁחֲרִית.‏

Only washing for pleasure is forbidden, therefor one washes Negel Vasser in the morning.

Since one has washed, one obviously says the Bracha of עַל נְטִילַת יָדַיִם.

> וְיִזָּהֵר שֶׁלֹּא יִרְחַץ רַק אֶצְבְּעוֹתָיו, שֶׁזֶּהוּ עִקַּר הָרְחִיצָה בְּשַחֲרִית, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁרוּחַ רָעָה שׁוֹרָה עַל הָאֶצְבָּעוֹת.‏

However, since "washing hands" - according to most opinions - is only until the knuckles, on Tisha B'Av and Yom Kippour one may not indulge in the *luxury* of washing until the wrist, (as one usually tries to do, if one has enough water).

> וְכֵן אִם הָיוּ יָדָיו מְלֻכְלָכוֹת בְּטִיט וְכַדּוֹמֶה, מֻתָּר לִרְחוֹץ בְּמָקוֹם הַמְלֻכְלָךְ. וְכֵן כְּשֶׁעוֹשֶׂה צְרָכָיו, מֻתָּר לִרְחוֹץ יָדָיו קְצָת כְּדַרְכּוֹ תָמִיד. ‏

[Since only washing for pleasure is forbidden,] if one's hands are dirty, one may wash the dirty parts. Similarly, after going to the bathroom, one may wash one's hands "a little" in the way one normally does. [IOW, if you always soap your hands after the bathroom, you may do so, but keep it to a minimum, concentrating on hygiene and no more.]

> וְכֵן לִתְפִלַּת מִנְחָה, יִרְחַץ אֶצְבְּעוֹתָיו.‏

The Kitzur adds that even for Mincha one may wash one's hands [minimally]; to reinforce that it's not only for morning prayers.

> נָשִׁים הַמְבַשְּׁלוֹת וּצְרִיכוֹת לְהָדִיחַ הַמַּאֲכָלִים, מֻתָּרוֹת. דְּהָא אֵינָן מִתְכַּוְּנוֹת לִרְחִיצָה.

Not only is hygiene and ritual washing allowed, but *incidental* washing is also allowed. Thus one is allowed to wash food [for kids to eat, or for after the fast], even though one's hands get very wet, since one is not doing so for pleasure.

> הַהוֹלֵךְ לְצָרְכֵי מִצְוָה וְאֵין לְפָנָיו דֶּרֶךְ אַחֶרֶת, רַק לַעֲבֹר בַּמַּיִם, עוֹבֵר בַּמַּיִם, בֵּין בַּהֲלִיכָתוֹ בֵּין בַּחֲזִירָתוֹ וְאֵינוֹ חוֹשֵׁשׁ. אֲבָל אִם הוֹלֵךְ בִּשְׁבִיל מָמוֹנוֹ, בַּהֲלִיכָתוֹ מֻתָּר, וּבַחֲזִירָתוֹ אָסוּר. ‏

If one travels for a Mitzva [to visit the sick or one's parents, or to go to shul, for example] and the only way is through a body of water, one may cross the water and get wet [if there's not boat available], both on one's way there, and even on the way back home.

However, if one travels through water for financial gain / business, one may go but not return through water.

Even if you use the [third definition](http://www.answers.com/topic/lave#American_Heritage_Dictionary_ds) of *lave* `to refresh or soothe as if by washing`, your statement is still incorrect:

> הַבָּא מִן הַדֶּרֶךְ וְרַגְלָיו כֵּהוֹת, מֻתָּר לְרָחֳצָן בַּמַיִם.‏

After a long trip by foot, if one's feet are sore, one may wash them with water.

All the above comes for Hilchot Tisha B'Av, but they are essentially the same for Yom Kippour, as the Kitzur says in סימן קלג - הלכות יום הכפורים :

> בְּיוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים אֵינוֹ אָסוּר רַק בִּרְחִצָה שֶׁל תַּעֲנוּג

On Yom Kippour only washing for pleasure is forbidden, The Kitzur then refers you to Hilchot Tisha B'Av for details.